# Why are there no domain redirects to sites with unique names?

Tags: support, hyperlinks, site-name

The URL to Cross Validated is stats.stackexchange.com. How many people look for the site with the "Cross Validated" domain alias? Why not set up a redirect?

Comment: There is `crossvalidated.com`.

Comment: I didn't know that. Thanks for the tip. Anyway, it is so easy to create an alias... I wonder how many people try the wrong urls.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there are in fact such domain redirects. However, they're not via the stackexchange.com domain, but by dedicated domain names.

The reason why these exist is in this post from the SE blog: [Domain Names: The Wrong Question](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/10/05/domain-names-the-wrong-question/).

In short, the earliest sites to be proposed through the then-new Area 51 process would get their own name and own domain, to align with the Trilogy sites (SO, SU, and SF). However, this was removed because discussions over site names would often get very drawn out, and in cases where a site would pick out a name, the corresponding domain would often already be registered. Thus, SE decided to stop giving new sites their own name and domain: instead, the site name would simply be the topic area, hosted as a subdomain of stackexchange.com.

However, sites that had previously been named and made it through beta (at the time a short process) got to keep their existing names. Cross Validated is one of those sites, and it does indeed have a domain redirect from that name, which is its former dedicated domain https://crossvalidated.com/.

A full table of sites that went through the Area 51 process back during this time:

| Site name | Topic area | Domain redirect | Current URL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Arqade | Gaming | https://arqade.com/ | https://gaming.stackexchange.com/ |
| Seasoned Advice | Cooking | https://seasonedadvice.com/ | https://cooking.stackexchange.com/ |
| Cross Validated | Statistics | https://crossvalidated.com/ | https://stats.stackexchange.com/ |

Some sites got to keep their name, but later moved to their topic name:

| Site former name | Topic name | Domain redirect | Current URL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Nothing to Install | Web Applications | https://nothingtoinstall.com/ | https://webapps.stackexchange.com/ |
| Not Programming Related | Programmers (former) | (none, skipped registering) | https://programmers.stackexchange.com/ (former) |

Also, one site that was moved from the previous Stack Exchange 1.0 model (pre-Area 51, in which site owners would pay SE to host their own public site) got to keep its name and former domain as a redirect:

| Site name | Topic area | Domain redirect | Current URL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Mi Yodeya | Judaism | https://mi.yodeya.com/ | https://judaism.stackexchange.com/ |

If there are any here that I missed, please edit or comment.

Comment: I am not sure if this answers that question why there is no crossvalidated.stackexchange.com which redirects to stats.stackexchange.com, given that crossvalidated.stackexchange.com is an honest mistake.